# python, urrlib2, http 500 error

Tags: python

I'm getting an http error 500: Internal Server Error when running the code pasted in below.  I've googled around here and in other places, but am not sure how to adapt a try/catch clause to my code to fix the error.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

First, the traceback:

```
File "BackupAttachments_Service_26_UNC.py", line 313, in <module>
  File "BackupAttachments_Service_26_UNC.py", line 296, in pull_replica
  File "BackupAttachments_Service_26_UNC.py", line 273, in replicate
  File "BackupAttachments_Service_26_UNC.py", line 52, in get_response
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 126, in urlopen
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 397, in open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 510, in http_response
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 435, in error
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 369, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 518, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

and now the code:

```
import json, urllib, urllib2, urlparse
import os, shutil
import time, datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import zipfile



# see other # #############################################
            # ---- values to be changed accordingly ----- #
            # #############################################


today = date.today()
todayString = today.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
# #############################################
# ---- Change service name_ as necessary ---- #
# #############################################
serviceTodayString = 'WAYS_riverbank_acquisition_'+ todayString
# #############################################
# ----- Change destination as necessary ----- #
# #############################################
## change to directory where service_date folder will be created
os.chdir(r'\\msds.wv.de\dfsroot\HV\GROUP\Dvkoord\GIS\Projekte\FE_WAYS\Projektbearbeitung\Geodaten\Download_der_mobil_erfassten_Daten')
if os.path.exists(serviceTodayString):
        shutil.rmtree(serviceTodayString)
## make folder for today's download
os.mkdir(serviceTodayString)
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
yesterdayString = yesterday.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
# #############################################
# ---- Change absolute path as necessary ---- #
# #############################################
serviceYesterdayString = r'\\msds.wv.de\dfsroot\HV\GROUP\Dvkoord\Software\intern\Export-download-AGOL-Daten\WAYS\WAYS_riverbank_acquisition_'+ yesterdayString


# ======================== #
#      REST functions      #
# ======================== #

## TOKEN ##
def get_response(url, query='', get_json=True):
    encoded = urllib.urlencode(query)
    request = urllib2.Request(url, encoded)
    if get_json:
        return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

def login (username, password):
    CREDENTIALS['username'] = username
    CREDENTIALS['password'] = password
    response = get_response(TOKEN_URL, CREDENTIALS)
    if 'error' in response:
        print response['error']
        exit()
    else:
        return response['token']


def check_service(service_url):
    url_parts = {"fs_url": None, "layer_url":None, "layer_id":None}
    components = os.path.split(service_url)
    if service_url == None:
        return True
    ## if layer id specified in url:
    elif (components[1].isdigit() and os.path.split(components[0])[1] == "FeatureServer"):
        url_parts["fs_url"] = components[0]
        url_parts["layer_url"] = service_url
        url_parts["layer_id"] = str(components[1])
        return url_parts
    ## if no layer id specified in url:
    elif components[1] == "FeatureServer":
        url_parts["fs_url"] = service_url
        return url_parts
    else:
        return False

def get_service_name(service_url):
    components = os.path.split(service_url)
    if components[1] == "FeatureServer":
        return os.path.split(components[0])[1]
    else:
        get_service_name(components[0])


def get_service_info(input_url, token):
    serviceInfo = get_response(input_url, {'f':'json', 'token':token})
    return serviceInfo

## none specified by default
def query_id_or_field(url, query, field=None):
    if field:
        query['outFields'] = field
        return get_response(url, query)['features']
    query['returnIdsOnly'] = 'true'
    return get_response(url, query)['objectIds']


def add_path(url, *args):
    for arg in args:
        url = urlparse.urljoin(url + "/", str(arg))
    return url

# ======================== #
#        OS functions      #
# ======================== #

def create_and_set_dir(directory_name):
    new_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory_name)
    os.makedirs(directory_name)
    os.chdir(directory_name)
    return new_dir

def pull_to_local(url, name, destination, file_format = ''):
    if destination:
        os.chdir(destination)
    if format:
        output = open(str(name) + '.%s'%file_format, 'wb')
    else:
        output = open(str(name), 'wb')
    output.write(url)
    output.close()

##def group_attachments(root_directory, new_directory):
##    os.chdir(root_directory)
##    attachments = [(os.path.join(directory, filename), filename) for directory,
##              dirnames, files in os.walk(root_directory) for filename in files if os.path.join(directory,filename)]
##    if len(attachments) > 0:
##        directory_path = create_and_set_dir(new_directory)
##        for attachment in attachments:
##            shutil.copy2(attachment[0], os.path.join(directory_path, attachment[1]))



# ======================== #
#          Queries         #
# ======================== #


CREDENTIALS = {
    'username': '',
    'password': '',
    'expiration': '60',
    'client': 'referer',
    'referer': 'www.arcgis.com',
    'f': 'json'
}

TOKEN_URL = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken"

ATTACHMENTS = {
    'where': '1=1',
    'token': '',
    'f': 'json'
}

REPLICA = {
    "geometry": '',
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryEnvelope",
    "inSR": '',
    "layerQueries": '',
    "layers": '0',
    "replicaName": "read_only_rep",
    "returnAttachments": 'true',
    "returnAttachmentsDataByUrl": 'true',
    "transportType": "esriTransportTypeEmbedded",
    "async": 'false',
    "syncModel": "none",
    "dataFormat": "filegdb",
    "token": '',
    "replicaOptions": '',
    "f": "json"
}


class App(object):
    ''' Class with methods to perform tasks with ESRI's REST service '''
    def __init__ (self, input_url, token, destination):
        self.input_url = input_url
        self.token = token
        self.destination = destination
        self.layer_url = None
        self.layer_id = None
        self.fs_url = self.check_input_url()

    def check_input_url(self):
        url_parts = check_service(self.input_url)
        self.layer_url = url_parts["layer_url"]
        self.layer_id = url_parts["layer_id"]
        if not self.layer_url:
            self.layer_url = add_path(url_parts["fs_url"], "0")
        return url_parts["fs_url"]

    def get_root_name(self):
        return get_service_name(self.fs_url) + "_" + time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")


    def attachment_report(self, root_directory, layer):
        os.chdir(root_directory)
        attachments = [(os.path.join(directory, filename), filename) for directory,
                  dirnames, files in os.walk(root_directory) for filename in files if os.path.join(directory,filename)]
        if len(attachments) > 0:
            attParentDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
            os.chdir(attParentDirectory)
            with open("Attachments Downloaded.txt", "a") as report:
                if len(attachments) > 1:
                    report.writelines('Aus dem Dienst ' + layer['name'] + ' wurden ' + str(len(attachments)) + ' Anhaenge heruntergeladen.\n')
                    report.close()
                else:
                    report.writelines('Aus dem Dienst ' + layer['name'] + ' wurde ' + str(len(attachments)) + ' Anhang heruntergeladen.\n')
                    report.close()


    def find_attachments(self, query, layer):
        root_file = create_and_set_dir(layer['name'])
        layer_query = add_path(self.fs_url, layer['id'], 'query')
        feature_ids = query_id_or_field(layer_query, query)
        for feature in feature_ids:
            os.chdir(root_file)
            img_url = add_path(self.fs_url, layer['id'], feature,
                'attachments')
            attachments = get_response(img_url, query)['attachmentInfos']
##            print 'attachments:'
##            print attachments
            if len(attachments) > 0:
                create_and_set_dir(str(feature))
                for attachment in attachments:
                    attachment_url = add_path(img_url, attachment['id'], 'download')
                    attachment_file = get_response(attachment_url, {'token':self.token}, get_json = False)
                    if '.' not in attachment['name']:
                        attExtension = str(attachment['contentType']).split('/')[1]
                        pull_to_local(attachment_file, attachment['name'] + '_GlobalID_' + attachment['parentID'],
                            '', attExtension)
                    else:
                        nameWoExt = str(attachment['name']).split('.')[0]
                        ext = str(attachment['name']).split('.')[1]
                        pull_to_local(attachment_file, nameWoExt + '_GlobalID_' + attachment['parentID'],
                            '', ext)
        self.attachment_report(root_file, layer)
##        group_attachments(root_file, "ALL")


    def pull_attachments(self, query):
        query['token'] = self.token
        os.chdir(self.destination)
        layers = get_service_info(self.fs_url, self.token)['layers']
        root_name = "Anlagen"
        service_file = create_and_set_dir(root_name)
        attachments = get_service_info(self.layer_url,
            self.token)['hasAttachments']
        if self.layer_id and attachments:
            self.find_attachments(query, layers[int(self.layer_id)])
        else:
            for layer in layers:
                if get_service_info(add_path(self.fs_url, layer['id']),
                    self.token)['hasAttachments']:
                    os.chdir(service_file)
                    self.find_attachments(query, layer)


    def replicate(self, query):
        replica_url = add_path(self.fs_url, 'createReplica')
        zip_url = get_response(replica_url, query)['responseUrl']
        zip_file = get_response(zip_url, get_json=False)
        geodaten = os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.destination, 'Geodaten'))
        ## put zip in Geodaten directory
        os.chdir(self.destination + '\\Geodaten')
        output = pull_to_local(zip_file, self.get_root_name(), geodaten, 'zip')
        files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(files[0])
        unzipped = zipped.extractall()
        subdiretories = [x[0] for x in os.walk(os.getcwd())]
        os.rename(os.path.basename(subdiretories[1]), self.get_root_name() + '.gdb')


    def pull_replica(self, query):
        query['token'] = self.token
        layers = get_service_info(self.fs_url, self.token)['layers']
        if self.layer_id:
            query['layers'] = self.layer_id
            self.replicate(query)
        else:
            query['layers'] = [layer['id'] for layer in layers]
            self.replicate(query)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TOKEN = login("user", "password")
    # #############################################
    # ----- Change service url as necessary ----- #
    # #############################################
    INPUT_URL = "http://services1.arcgis.com/0cr41EdkajvOA232/arcgis/rest/services/WAYS_riverbank_acquisition/FeatureServer"
    # #############################################
    # ----- Change destination as necessary ----- #
    # #############################################
    DEST = r"\\msds.wv.de\dfsroot\HV\GROUP\Dvkoord\GIS\Projekte\FE_WAYS\Projektbearbeitung\Geodaten\Download_der_mobil_erfassten_Daten" + '\\' + serviceTodayString
    # delete folder from yesterday if present
    if os.path.exists(serviceYesterdayString):
        shutil.rmtree(serviceYesterdayString)
    RUN = App(INPUT_URL, TOKEN, DEST)
    RUN.pull_replica(REPLICA)
    RUN.pull_attachments(ATTACHMENTS)
```

Comment: Have you considered using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) instead?

Comment: Where do you want to use your try catch? Is it the last block of code where if __name__ = "__main__" starts?

Comment: using requests will require a significant re-write, and it is also not a native module (which I would like to avoid using if possible). I'm not sure where the try/catch needs to go, which is part of my problem.  I assume it needs to be in the get_response def, but am also not sure how to incorporate it.